# Centrar form para login en ionic usando grid

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic2, ionic4

Quiero posicionar el form en medio usando grid. Me crea la rejilla pero no me desplaza el elemento cuando quiero establecer la propiedad grid-area. Cuál sería el problema ? es mi primera vez usando Ionic con Angular

El siguiente código está en tab1.page.html

```
<ion-content class="containerForm">
<form class="form">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Usuario:</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Contraseña:</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

Y éste sería el css

```
.containerForm{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas:    "top"
                           "mid"
                           "bot";
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.form{
   grid-area: mid;
}
```